# Is there any addon that can make javascript execute before the page loads?

Tags: firefox, scripting, greasemonkey

Well, greasemonkey can execute users script but only after the page loads fully. Is there any script that can take user script (javascript) and executes it before the page downlaods any elemts.
for instance, As soon as the HTML file is downloaded, the user script should execute so that i can prevents the download of embedded elements like flash, jpg, js files downloads

Comment: If you are asking how to write such a plugin, then it is programming related. But if you just want to ask for help Googling for an existing plugin to a browser, that's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [content-document-global-created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) notification in the recent versions of Firefox that fires before the page started loading.

[Jetpack SDK](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/) has a Page mods module that uses that notification to let you write greasemonkey-like snippets. That's kind of an "addon that can make javascript execute before the page loads".

I don't know how you'd implement content blocking via such script, though.

The common way to do content blocking is via [nsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIContentPolicy), which is what Adblock uses.